# How to conditionally render default values in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm building a Login and signup modal form and in the modal form, the user can switch between login and signup form by clicking a button. But I'm using same default values for both login and signup form and I don't need the `name` property as the default value for the login form, I only need the `name` property in the sign up page. So, my question is can we dynamically render defaut values? For example, if `isLogin` true, render `loginDefaultValues` otherwise render `signupDefaultValues`.

```
const { handleSubmit, control, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: isLogin ? loginDefaultValues : signupDefaultValues;
})
```

Or is there any other better way to handle this?

Form Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const signupDefaultValues = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const loginDefaultValues = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      name: ""
    }
  });
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (isLogin) {
      console.log("Login:", data.email, data.password);
    } else {
      console.log("Signup:", data.name, data.email, data.password);
    }
  };

  const toggleForm = () => {
    setIsLogin(!isLogin);
    reset(isLogin ? loginDefaultValues : signupDefaultValues);
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <h2>{isLogin ? "Login" : "Signup"}</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <Controller
              name="email"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => <input {...field} type="email" />}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <Controller
              name="password"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => <input {...field} type="password" />}
            />
          </div>
          {!isLogin && (
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <Controller
                name="name"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => <input {...field} type="text" />}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <button onClick={toggleForm}>{isLogin ? "Signup" : "Login"}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it working the way you did it? Do you have any errors or something is not woking as it should?

Comment: Yes, it's working. But I'm not sure whether we can update the default values the way I'm doing.

Comment: Initially, I have `name` field in the signupDefaultValues and when I switch to the login form, it doesn't have a `name` field.